# How to display "Add button" on the Sonata Admin with many to many relations

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

How to display the "Add button" on the Sonata Admin with many to many relations?

With Many-to-One I can use ModelType::class.
But M-to-M doesn't support it.
When I use "null", I can see a list of the items only.
When I use "CollectionType::class", I can add new items, but I don't see other items.

```
        ->add('students', null, [
            'label' => 'Students',
            'by_reference' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ]);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide us with your entity code. Check if relations are properly set.